# VBScript CopyFile reports Error 53 File Not Found, but has successfully copied file

Tags: error-handling, vbscript

I'm trying to diagnose an issue with VBScript `FileSystemObject.CopyFile`, it's reporting Error 53: File Not Found, but it has successfully copied the file!  I've tried variations of the `CopyFile` command, with full destination name or just folder etc no difference, it always copies the file.

Worse, if I purposefully break it, by changing the source file name, I still get Error 53, which is the exact situation I'm trying to catch and report.

```
On Error Resume Next
```

```
'copy the officeUI xml to the Microsoft Office folder
filePath = profilePath & "\Microsoft\Office\"
if not WshFSO.FolderExists(filePath) then
    WshFSO.CreateFolder filePath
end if
WshFSO.CopyFile scriptPath & "\Access.officeUI", filePath, True

'copy the foo client zip to \foo
filePath = profilePath & "\foo\"
if not WshFSO.FolderExists(filePath) then
    WshFSO.CreateFolder filePath
end if
WshFSO.CopyFile localZip, filePath, True
if Err.Number <> 0 then
    'catch that the copy failed
    msg = "Failed to copy Foo, please report this to Help Desk." _
        & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & "Citrix Server: " & WshNetwork.ComputerName _
        & vbCrLf & "Error: " & err.Number & " - " & err.Description      
    WshShell.Popup msg, , "Foo Launcher", 16
    Err.Clear
    WScript.Quit
end if
```

The error is occuring on the final `CopyFile` call.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was due to the Error handling logic in VBS, it was reporting the error number from an earlier line!  The `On Error Resume Next` allowed the code to continue to run, but subsequent calls, even successful ones, did not overwrite the `Err` object.  So when I did want to check the result, it picked up this previous error.

So from this I think that unless you want `If Err.Number...` everywhere is that before each 'block' of code you want to error check, clear the Err object first with `Err.Clear`.

I wish VBScript had `On Error Goto` like its cousin!